# Redis cache not working properly in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

For caching I use redis

```
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-namespace'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-rack-cache'
```

Using cache for html code in views

When I set cache using key it works. But when I get it not integrated even value exists

```
def cache(cache_name)
  value = $redis.get(cache_name)
  if value.nil?
    $redis.set(cache_name,yield,ex:5.minutes)
  else
    value
  end
end
```

in view

```
<% cache("key") do %>
   <h1>Header</h1>
<%end%>
```

Issue is that first time heading shows but next it not showing even value exists

Comment: Why did you write your own `cache` method and do not use the `cache` method that comes with Rails?

Comment: using `Rails.cache.fetch` block should do the needful

Comment: @spickermann because its a helper its common function

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon whats its purpose?

Comment: @spickermann but it should be work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
def cache(cache_name)
  Rails.cache.fetch(cache_name, expires_in: 5.minutes){ yield }
end
```

**UPDATE**

Rails already provides a helper to cache fragments, and it turns out to be the same name as your custom helper, so just change the name of your method

```
def set_cache(cache_name)
  Rails.cache.fetch(cache_name, expires_in: 5.minutes){ yield }
end
```

you view remains the same..

Comment: where this cache will store in redis?

Comment: I set in application.rb

Comment: config.cache_store = :redis_store, 'redis://localhost:6379/0/cache'

Comment: yes, it should work then, let me know if you still get the same error

Comment: same issue it not integrate html

Comment: either i need to parse it in json etc?

Comment: I want that html widget store in redis and after caching it will show form redis

Comment: if it is getting stored in redis, it most probably is string, try `.html_safe`

Comment: is it define in helper>